# Can't access WSDL without valid SOAPaction

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to look at a WSDL response to get a list of actions but it always fails without a valid SOAPAction header. Setting SOAPAction to an empty string returns same error.

```
Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: <some-value>
```

Using the content type optional value like so returns the same error:

`application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=<some-value>`

What is the proper order of operations to get the full WSDL response containing a valid set of actions? Other requests fail with the same error despite using the documented action name. Possibly it's listed differently in the WSDL

---

If I make a POST request to the documented wsdl url `https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/wsdl.aspx?ver=2021-11-01`

I get a document like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:tns="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2021-11-01/ldb/"
  targetNamespace="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2021-11-01/ldb/">
    <wsdl:import namespace="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2021-11-01/ldb/" location="rtti_2021-11-01_ldb.wsdl" />
    <wsdl:service name="ldb">
        <wsdl:port name="LDBServiceSoap" binding="tns:LDBServiceSoap">
            <soap:address location="https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb12.asmx" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="LDBServiceSoap12" binding="tns:LDBServiceSoap12">
            <soap12:address location="https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb12.asmx" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

If I then make a POST request to the listed service address `https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb12.asmx` I get 401 unauthorised.

I can then send a SOAP document containing the token I have for the service like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:service="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2014-02-20/ldb/" xmlns:types="http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2010-11-01/ldb/commontypes">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <types:AccessToken>
      <types:TokenValue>{{token}}</types:TokenValue>
    </types:AccessToken>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But then get a 500 internal server error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Unable to handle request without a valid action parameter. Please supply a valid soap action.</faultstring>
            <detail />
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But no value I use as the `SOAPAction` header returns anything other than `Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: valuehere`. Adding `?WSDL` to the url does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For any future googlers: I found the proper wsdl at:

`https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/rtti_2021-11-01_ldb.wsdl`

That lists the actual SOAPAction values that I can use to get past that error.

Now I just get even more unhelpful...

```xml
<soap:Fault>
    <soap:Code>
        <soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value>
    </soap:Code>
    <soap:Reason>
        <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Unexpected server error</soap:Text>
    </soap:Reason>
    <soap:Detail />
</soap:Fault>
```

Comment: Use https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb9.asmx  instead of https://lite.realtime.nationalrail.co.uk/OpenLDBWS/ldb12.asmx